# i dont understand this code from javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to JavaScript and I am wondering what this means in plain English.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please input a number between 5 and 10:</p>

<input id="demo" type="text">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Test Input</button>

<p id="message"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  ***  var message, x; ***
  ***  message = document.getElementById("message"); ***
  ***  message.innerHTML = ""; ***
    x = document.getElementById("demo").value;
    try { 
        if(x == "")  throw "is Empty";
        if(isNaN(x)) throw "not a number";
        if(x > 10)   throw "too high";
        if(x < 5)    throw "too low";
    }
    catch(err) {
        message.innerHTML = "Input " + err;
    }
    finally {
        document.getElementById("demo").value = "";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand the part between the ***'s. why are they tacking messaging and putting it in messaging? please help and define any programing words an extremely knew person would not understand.

than you very much.

Answer (score 2):

`var message, x;`

Declare two variables `message` and `x` which are currently undefined.

`message = document.getElementById("message");`

Now we assign the DOM node which has the id of "message" to the variable `message`

`message.innerHTML = "";`

We now empty out anything which might be inside the DOM container.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a line-by-line breakdown:

```
function myFunction() {
  // declare variables message and x with no value or type
  var message, x;

  // set message to the DOM element with the id of "message"
  message = document.getElementById("message");

  // set the inner HTML (the content inside the div) of message to be an empty string
  message.innerHTML = "";

  // set x to be the value of the DOM element with the id of "demo"  
  x = document.getElementById("demo").value;

  // try some cases
  try { 
      // if the x's value is an empty string, return a descriptive string
      if(x == "")  throw "is Empty";
      // if the x's value is a not a number, return a descriptive string
      if(isNaN(x)) throw "not a number";
      // if the x's value is greater than 10, return a descriptive string
      if(x > 10)   throw "too high";
      // if the x's value is less than 5, return a descriptive string
      if(x < 5)    throw "too low";
  }
  // catch an error if none of the cases match
  catch(err) {
      // display an error message in the message DOM element
      message.innerHTML = "Input " + err;
  }
  // finally clause executes after try and catch execute, but before the statements following the try statement
  finally {
      // set the value of the demo DOM element to be an empty string
      document.getElementById("demo").value = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: im just still wondering how he was confused by the lines he highlighted vs the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

```
var message, x;
```

This declares that the variables `message` and `x` will be used within this scope.  That is, we want the variables `message` and `x` within the function `myFunction()`, and not variables `message` and `x` that might be defined outside of it.

```
message = document.getElementById("message");
```

The variable `message` will contain the actual element with the id of `message` on the page.  From here forward, we can call methods and set properties on the variable `message`, as it is the element on the page itself.

```
message.innerHTML = "";
```

This is a way to empty the contents of `message`.  Setting it to empty, basically.  In the code, a message can be added if there is an error.  The person who wrote this decided to clear any previous error message first, so that if this function succeeded, there would be no error message shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  // I am going to use the variables message and x in function
  // but they don´t have a value yet
  var message, x; 
  // assign message to be the element with id="message"
  message = document.getElementById("message");
  // remove all text from message
  message.innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: I just realized he added the asterisks himself to highlight the code. Feeling very sheepish.